# Проблемы с Template для UserControl

Tags: wpf, xaml, usercontrol

Есть пользовательский элемент управления

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication4.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication4">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style TargetType="local:UserControl1">
                <Style.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                        <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Background="Beige">
                                            <ContentPresenter/>
                                        </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style.Setters>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
</UserControl>
```

Вот его использование на форме

```
<Grid>

    <local:UserControl1>
        <StackPanel>
            <Label>asdf</Label>
            <TextBlock Text="qwe"/>
        </StackPanel>

    </local:UserControl1>

</Grid>
```

В итоге `Border` располагается на всю форму (специально задал цвет заливки и контура для наглядности), а вот контент не выводится. Что я делаю не так? Судя по примерам все должно работать.

VS 2015
FW 4.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы забыли указать `TargetType` у `ControlTemplate`

Рабочий пример:

```
  <UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style TargetType="testApp:UserControl1">
            <Style.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="UserControl">
                            <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Background="Beige">
                                <ContentPresenter/>
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style.Setters>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Comment: Может быть, даже лучше будет указать конкретный тип (в моем примере - `testApp:UserControl1`) вместо `UserControl`

Comment: Если все дело в этом, то почему отрисовывается `Border`?

Comment: Потому что для отрисовки Border'а не нужно знать конкретный тип, к которому применяется шаблон. А ContentPresenter неявно требует Content, судя по всему.

Answer (score 2):

Если сделать так, то работает

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication4.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication4">
    <UserControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Control">
            <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Background="Beige">
                <ContentPresenter/>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </UserControl.Template>
</UserControl>
```

Но почему не работает через стили? Тема все еще открыта.